# Dependency of Stark effect on Quantum numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, quantum-information, atomic-physics

I have read many sources which tell me that the Stark and Zeeman effects, which Bohr's theory had trouble explaining, were explained by the introduction of the magnetic quantum number.  But doesn't the Stark effect depend on the principal quantum number ($n$) while the Zeeman effect depends on the magnetic quantum number?  Does the Stark effect depend on both of these?